# Change Folder Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I started off with changing to the folder I want to change permissions for, and that is the opt folder.

```
$ cd /opt/
test@testVM:/opt$
```

So I tried changing the permissions for this folder now using:

```
sudo chmod 775
```

And that hasn't worked. It showed this message:

```
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

There is something I am forgetting or leaving out.

Please can you show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the "change what" part of the command.

Most commands are like a simple "verb-noun" type structure. (Which, if you think about it, tends to explain why we sound like Yoda when we talk)

You said "chmod 755"... which is the verb... where's the noun?

```
sudo chmod 755 .         # the '.' means 'here'
```

-or-

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt      # always better to specify exactly what you want
```

**My** question is going to be:  Why do you want to do that?  What need do you have to change the permissions of /opt?   (not that it's vitally important for me to know, but *you* should know that changing permissions of anything that's not in your /home folder is *usually* not a good idea.  Think about what you're doing.)

Comment: I am using a program called WinSCP (like an FTP server) to copy files from my local machine to the Ubuntu machine (VM), and need to have the permissions to copy to that folder. Everytime I try copying a folder across, it says the following: "scp: /opt/{folder name}: Permission denied"

Comment: No worries, but `755` isn't going to allow you to write in that subdirectory either.  Why not create a subdirectory in your home and have it saved there?  It's your system, do as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify directory in arguments.
If you want to apply changes to the current directory, just add  `.` at the end (or even the full path):

```
sudo chmod 775 .
```

otherwise it will give you the error.

ps. If you ran `chmod --help` as suggested, you would have seen:

```
 $ chmod --help
Usage:  chmod [OPTION]... MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
   or:  chmod [OPTION]... OCTAL-MODE FILE...
   or:  chmod [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chmod 775 .`

You can just do `sudo chmod 775 /opt` without `cd`.

Bye the way, `-R` option of `chmod` is recursively mode changing.

`man chmod` for more information.