# Is insecure to give users permissions to apps in /opt?

Tags: linux, permissions, security

I'm working with some apps (the best example i can give is Firefox Developer Edition) that i put in the /opt folder. These apps work perfectly until they need to apply and update, and that's because /opt is owned by root, and to write those apps in the /opt folder i use the sudo command when i unpack the apps. To "fix" this, my best solution was to chmod, chown and chgrp the apps (each app folder, no de /opt folder) to my user, and give permissions to users to write inside the apps folders:

```
[user@localhost /opt] $ ls -lah
total 76K
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root        root        4,0K dic 28 22:32 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 20 root        root        4,0K nov 13 02:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x   7 MyUser      MyGroup     4,0K nov 24 21:46 android-studio
drwxr-xr-x  10 MyUser      MyGroup     4,0K dic 17 21:45 firefox-dev
drwxrwxr-x   2 MyUser      MyGroup     4,0K dic 28 22:34 linux-wbfs-manager
drwxr-xr-x.  5 MyUser      MyGroup     4,0K mar 25  2015 sublime_text_2
drwx------.  3 MyUser      MyGroup     4,0K dic  2 14:53 tor-browser_en-US
drwxrwxr-x   4 MyUser      MyGroup     4,0K dic 17 19:28 WordPress.com
```

Now, i'm wondering if this a good practice or is insecure. Until now, i didn't have any problem, but i'm using browsers and other apps with network access.

This questions differs from [Change folder permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/change-folder-permissions) because I'm not asking how to change the permissions but to know if that is considered an insecure practice.

Comment: At the very least, I'd set the "chmod +t" flag, so users couldn't edit other users' files, but allowing write access to /opt/anything still seems dangerous. Most programs like these should create a subdirectory in the users home directory.

Comment: It's not clear to me why users need to write to `/opt` at all. Apart from when you (the administrator) update the tools themselves of course.

Comment: If one's home-directory is normally hidden with 0700, a shared location such as /opt can be useful.

Comment: @ThomasDickey that question do not solve my problem. I don't have problems with the `chmod` command, my question is about the security of having folders inside `/opt` with user permissions. Please consider unmark like duplicate because is not the same question.

Comment: @roaima The main problem mentioned in this question is that Firefox has an automatic update feature which checks for updates when a user runs Firefox. If the Firefox directory in `/opt/` is owned by root, then Firefox does not have the permission to write these updates. The common solution is to `chown` the `/opt/firefox` directory to your user: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/firefox/` to allow these automatic updates.

Comment: @mchid I don't allow users to update shared applications. That's a massive security breach just waiting to happen

Comment: @roaima Yes I agree. But even without other users on the system, op would still need to `chown`  the `/opt/firefox/` directory to `$USER:$USER` to allow Firefox the permission to apply automatic updates. So it still seems somewhat insecure — because if Firefox were installed using a package manager for example, write permission would be restricted to `root:root` for these directories.

Comment: @roaima I guess one solution would be to write a script to download and apply the updates manually instead of automatic updates. Not sure about Firefox Developer however, but Firefox Nightly applies an update nearly every time you run the browser, multiple times per day. Although I guess it wouldn't be impossible to link the script to the desktop file and use pkexec to ask for a password when needed. The only problem there would be unnecessary downloads from the mozilla servers. Maybe figure out a way to check the version number based on the URL redirect before downloading the file I guess.

Comment: @roaima It would be nice if Firefox automatic updates would go through pkexec to ask for permission when needed and then revoke permission when the update is complete but I haven't looked into that.

Comment: @mchid that would be a nightmare scenario on a multiuser system. Consider if you're happily working with certain extensions, and you have (say) a project deadline. Another user comes along with without any warning accepts the "upgrade now" option - but unfortunately that upgrade knocks out one of your essential addons. You now can't finish your project in the time available. _That's_ why there are planned and scheduled upgrade routes on properly managed multiuser systems

Comment: So in the end, is insecure or not?